# How can I make my macbook pro liquid proof?

Tags: macbook-pro

As I hang around those who are toilet training, and people who *really* dislike macs, I'm wondering if there is any way to make my macbook pro urine proof?

**Update**

What about adding a waterproof case, if any exist? I'd like to be able to use it at the same time if possible.

Comment: Some cats are notorious for marking computers, however if you are looking to protect the hardware, it doesn't really matter what liquid or mindset the vandals possess, no? (Or are you suggesting that non-toddlers are goading your toddlers to action?)

Comment: @bmike I know some grown ups that really, *really* dislike macs, I wouldn't put **anything past them**.

Comment: Like anything you place on it will deter an adult intent on vandalizing your property. Would you consider editing this to be a little more usable for the general population? It runs the risk of being closed as worded (and with the existing answers you have attracted - this is unlikely to be of long term use)

Comment: @bmike it was edited to find out how to waterproof a mbp, I think that's pretty generic, no? It's already on the front page of google for 'how to waterproof a macbook pro'

Comment: Let's discuss this in [chat] or on [meta] if you want to stake out new ground on waterproofing.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think you are going about this the wrong way.  You are looking defensively when you should be on offense.

Consider getting something like a privacy shield to place around the urinator:

[image]

Another alternative might be to simply bring physical pain into the mix.  Wounding the urinator that sprays wildly towards you and the Macbook might make the urinator realize that control is important.

Again, think offense...not defense.

Comment: Oh god I can't stop laughing… thank you! You deserve that upvote! ;-)

Comment: What a great idea! I can use the laptop at the same time!

Answer (score 2):

No, Apple do not sell any MacBooks that are liquid-proof.

You can buy various waterproof bags, even ones that are specifically designed for laptops such as the [Aqua Quest waterproof sleeve](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Waterproof-Laptop-Macbook-Padded-Sleeve/dp/B006542PRG):

[image]

…however you can't use your MacBook at the same time though!

Comment: Thanks, I have updated my question however in light of your response

Answer (score 2):

The guy near the end of this video shows how he waterproofed his iPhone.  I imagine applying this method to the major components of the MBP will go a long way to ensuring "liquid" won't destroy anything.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DZrjXSsfxMQ

And for disassemnly, iFixit can help you there.

http://www.ifixit.com/Device/MacBook_Pro

So, disassemble your Macbook Pro, waterproof the components, especially the motherboard.  I doubt you'll be able to submerge it afterwards, but it'll resist spills.

Also, I haven't actually done this or anything, so, you know, no lawyers.